# Binding Semantic UI DropDown in Polymer

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-1.0, semantic-ui

I currently data-bind `<paper-radio-button>` but I now want to use a dropdown instead. I want something like this:

```
// inside a dom-module template
<select value="{{selection}}" class="ui dropdown" id="select">
 <option value="a">Alpha A</option>
 <option value="b">Alpha B</option>
 <option value="c">Alpha D</option>
</select>
<script>
  $('#select').dropdown();
</script>

Polymer({
 is: 'my-app',
 selectionChanged: function() {
  if (this.selection === 'c') {
   alert('Teen Wolf');
  }
 }
});
```

How to get the selected option in the [semantic dropdown menu](http://semantic-ui.com/modules/dropdown.html)?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I haven't managed to get Polymer working with Semantic-UI with 2-way data binding. The only way around this I'm currently using is to do the *binding* myself.

You can bind to the *onChange* event when initializing the dropdown:

```
$('#select').dropdown({
    onChange: function(value, text, $choice) {
        this.selected = value;
    }.bind(this)
});
```

You can also modify *selectionChanged* function to set the dropdown if needed, in case you need to set the *selection* value from elsewhere. Not sure if you need to protect against an event-loop though:

```
selectionChanged: function(oldValue, newValue) {
    // Just in case, check the dropdown value before setting it
    if ($('#select').dropdown('get value') !== this.selection)
        $('#select').dropdown('set value', newValue);

    // Continue doing other stuff with your selection value here
    // ...
    // ...
}
```

Comment: I have tried that exactly and nothing works. I guess we cant bind this type of dropdown as in the console, I dont see the value sets to nothing.

Comment: You may be able to bind the select element if you use the `<div>` style instantiation with the hidden input, rather than using the `<select>` element. Did you have a jsfiddle setup with your configuration? That would be ideal to help you out on.